# Can this typescript type guard be made to work?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am trying to write a generic utility type that allows me to track the status of asynchronously loaded REST data, without polluting the codebase too much.

I came up with the solution below, however the type guard doesn't infer the loaded type T:

```
interface _LoadingStatus {
  restStatus: number
}

type Loading<T> = T | (_LoadingStatus & Partial<T>);

function isLoaded<T>(data: Loading<T>): data is T {
    return typeof data !== 'object' || data == null || ! ("restStatus" in data);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
interface AppSetting {
  country: string
}

declare const loadSettings: () => Loading<AppSetting>

const settings = loadSettings();

if (settings?.country != null) {
  settings.country.toUpperCase()
} else {
  settings.restStatus
}

if (isLoaded(settings)) {
  settings.country.toUpperCase()
}
```

The type guard works as expected if I don't include Partial:

```
export type Loading<T> = T | _LoadingStatus;
```

however I wanted to be able to access the value without using the typeguard (the data is used in many places in legacy code):

```
const settings :Loading<AppSetting>  = loadSettings();
if (settings?.country != null) { ... }
```

Thanks!

[Edit]: the sample above actually works, the narrowing only fails when the type guard is used behind VueJS and other 3rd-party functions. So there may be nothing wrong with the approach...

```
const settings = computedAsync<Loading<TenantSettings>>(async () => {
    try {
        return await epClient.get<TenantSettings>("settings");
    }
    catch (e) {
        return { restStatus: e.statusCode }
    }
});

watch(settings, (settings) => {
      if (! isLoaded(settings)) return;
    settings.country   // FAILS
}

watch(settings, (settings : Loading<TenantSettings>) => {
      if (! isLoaded(settings)) return;
    settings.country   // WORKS
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried to clean up the sample, and I also found out that the issue is indeed coming from type inference through 3rd-party functions (VueJS), I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Argh, I did not want to do that, apologies. I will fix it, however the change in Partial makes no difference: both types work when used directly and both fails when used behind VueJS functions.

Comment: So I guess you should tag the question with vuejs or something?  If you can't provide a [mre] of your issue then the question will probably be closed as needing debugging details.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: Seems to be a Vue issue if `settings` is not getting inferred properly in the watch method. Your function works fine when it receives a properly typed value.

Comment: Yes I agree. sorry for wasting your time! I don't see how to close the question, not sure if I should delete it altogether...